# unable to connect to sql server VM through web app hosted on another azure VM

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, virtual-machine

I am unable to connect to a windows azure virtual machine hosting SQL server on it through my web application hosted on another azure VM. I am getting an application error on login page itself which says "object reference not set to instance of object". I am not able to connect to the database.

Comment: please supply more information, can you make a udl check from another machine to validate connectivity ? are the VMs in the same private network ? can you ping between them ? are the TCP ports regarding the sql open for that network ?

Comment: both the VMs are in different private networks. TCP ports for the sql VM are open but I am unable to ping the SQL VM from the web app VM.

Comment: I will give a short answer hopefully it would help

Answer (score 1):

In order to set connecrivity between a SQL server running on a VM to any other application you must make sure there are both connecrivity Settings for the SQL server and the VM it self :

The VM :

the vm has its firewall that blocks any access for the VM except the rules you define in the firewall, if you wish to access the vm you must open the relevent ports in the firewall. (BTW to ping the server enable ICMP on the firewall ...)

Make notes :
- if you wish to open a port inside the private networks its done by the firewall but if you wish to go outside the private network make sure you need to set endpoints in the azure portal and relate to the machine by that ports.

- if you wish to open the ports for relevant IPs only i would tell you that the azure endpoints (unless you set them by the azure power shell) are defined behind the azure load balance and the access to the VM would come from the load balancer IP ... a way to overcome this is use the new feature the azure gives - endpoints acl (i think its in preview thay havnt been realy clear about this) or to open the load balancer ip.

Regarding the SQL server,
when trying to connect to a sql server the following communication is happening :
- the app is sending a UDP message to the server and asking in which port should it access the server , that udp message is sent in port 1434 - so you should grant access to that port also,
- if dynamic ports are enabled in the sql server settings the server may the sql server listens to that udp 1434 and returns an unused tcp port which than it will listen for communication from that app.
- if you disable the dynamic ports and set to the default port of sql communication (tcp 1433) you would than be able to open that port with the udp 1434 from the machine and the communication will work, if that is not a security issue for you you can allow all the ports and let the dynamic ports to be enabled.

anyway - you need to combine all these settings - relevant to your servers structure to enable the communication.

Hoped i helped

Comment: thanku so much for this detailed explanation. will surely try these settings and let u know.